# I'm create div via js, but it doesn't appear on my page

Tags: javascript, html

In my JS code, I created a new div. I checked, and it isn't `null`, but it doesn't appear on my page.

This is my code:

```
  snake.push(document.createElement('div'));
  snake[0].style.width = '1000px';
  snake[0].style.height = '1000px';
  snake[0].style.background = 'red';
  snake[0].style.color = 'blue';
  console.log(snake[0]);
```

I used `console.log()` to check, that `snake[0]` isn't `null`

`snake` is empty list: `let snake = [];`

Why `snake[0]` doesn't appear on the page?

Comment: Yuo never append the DIV to the DOM.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild

Comment: And why are you using `snake[0]`? To access the element you just pushed, it should be `snake[snake.length-1]`.

Comment: Yes, but i know that my list consists of 1 element yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've created the element but you did not attach it to the DOM.
Take a look here:
https://dev.to/desoga/7-javascript-methods-that-aids-dom-manipulation-kkj

It's a list of helpful methods that you can use while working on DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

As others have commented, what you are looking for is `appendChild`. This method enables DOM nodes to be added as children of other DOM nodes. It is very closely related to the [composite pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).

```js
var snake = [];
snake.push(document.createElement('div'));
snake[0].style.width = '1000px';
snake[0].style.height = '1000px';
snake[0].style.background = 'red';
snake[0].style.color = 'blue';
console.log(snake[0]);
document.body.appendChild(snake[0]);
```

In this case I've appended `snake[0]` to the `body`.